# Feet size correlated with testosterone in women?

Tags: human-biology

Do females with bigger feet have more testosterone? Examples:

1.Regular-sized women with larger than average shoe size

2.Taller women who tend to wear larger shoe sizes more often than not

I ask because some people say that when women feet get bigger they resemble men's feet more. I ask if this such resemblance is indicative of testosterone higher naturally in these women vs. women with smaller feets. I hope someone can understand and apply these methods to an answer.

For example my sister have bigger feet (size 10 in women's Canada) and people have always told her, especially family, that her feet look like a guy's feet/structure more because they are bigger.

Like the genes that mold the bone structure and design of the foot could having higher test. impact the feet and give the women with larger types feet that people say are more masculine more natural test?

Comment: can you add any scholarly publication to support asking this question? this sounds unfounded... also, how does testosterone affect bone growth? you suggest that bone length is somehow increased by increasing concentrations of testosterone in the blood - is there any evidence for that at all?